# it is able call from asterisk with no static ip

Tags: asterisk

my aim  is

1. asterisk server with static IP.
2. asterisk server with "no static" IP but with land phone

can i call with registration 2 in 1 and use 1 for calling with 2

## (land line calling)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can register server2 on server1 like softphone and do calling.

See http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+Connect+2+servers